# Ceph Monitor out of quorum

Tags: ceph

we're experiencing a problem with one of our ceph monitors. Cluster uses 3 monitors and they are all up&running. They can communicate with each other and gives a relevant ceph -s output. However quorum shows second monitor is down. The ceph -s output from supposedly down monitor is below:

```
cluster:
    id:     bb1ab46a-d282-4530-bf5c-021e9c940958
    health: HEALTH_WARN
            insufficient standby MDS daemons available
            noout flag(s) set
            9 large omap objects
            47 pgs not deep-scrubbed in time
            application not enabled on 2 pool(s)
            1/3 mons down, quorum mon1,mon3

  services:
    mon:        3 daemons, quorum mon1,mon3 (age 3d), out of quorum: mon2
    mgr:        mon1(active, since 3d)
    mds:        filesystem:1 {0=mon1=up:active}
    osd:        77 osds: 77 up (since 3d), 77 in (since 2w)
                flags noout
    rbd-mirror: 1 daemon active (12512649)
    rgw:        1 daemon active (mon1)

  data:
    pools:   13 pools, 1500 pgs
    objects: 65.36M objects, 23 TiB
    usage:   85 TiB used, 701 TiB / 785 TiB avail
    pgs:     1500 active+clean

  io:
    client:   806 KiB/s wr, 0 op/s rd, 52 op/s wr
```

systemctl status ceph-mon@2.service shows:

```
ceph-mon@2.service - Ceph cluster monitor daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ceph-mon@.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Tue 2020-12-08 12:12:58 +03; 28s ago
  Process: 2681 ExecStart=/usr/bin/ceph-mon -f --cluster ${CLUSTER} --id %i --setuser ceph --setgroup ceph (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2681 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 08 12:12:48 mon2 systemd[1]: Unit ceph-mon@2.service entered failed state.
Dec 08 12:12:48 mon2 systemd[1]: ceph-mon@2.service failed.
Dec 08 12:12:58 mon2 systemd[1]: ceph-mon@2.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 08 12:12:58 mon2 systemd[1]: Stopped Ceph cluster monitor daemon.
Dec 08 12:12:58 mon2 systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for ceph-mon@2.service
Dec 08 12:12:58 mon2 systemd[1]: Failed to start Ceph cluster monitor daemon.
Dec 08 12:12:58 mon2 systemd[1]: Unit ceph-mon@2.service entered failed state.
Dec 08 12:12:58 mon2 systemd[1]: ceph-mon@2.service failed.
```

Restarting, Stop/Starting, Enable/Disabling the monitor daemon did not work. Docs mention the monitor asok file in var/run/ceph and i don't have it in the supposed directory yet the other monitors have their   asok files right in place. And now im in a state that i can't even stop the monitor daemon on second monitor it only stays at failed state. There is no logs shown in /var/log/ceph monitor logs. What am i supposed to do? I don't have much experience in ceph so i don't want to change things without being absolutely sure in order to avoid messing up the cluster.

Comment: First, your MON is not up & running as you state in the beginning, it says "failed" in the status. Check disk space, syslog, dmesg on the second MON to rule out any other issues. Then run `systemctl reset-failed`and start MON again. There should be log entries. How did you deploy ceph? It doesn't seem to be Octopus yet so probably not with cephadm? If you can't bring it up try to create a new MON, it's a light-weight service and can be setup quite quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to start the service manually on MON2 with:

```
/usr/bin/ceph-mon -f --cluster Ceph --id 2 --setuser ceph --setgroup ceph
```

Comment: This solved my problem but it still showed the daemon status as failed. So i did some digging and found there is an inconsistency between somewhere in the config files, when i fixed it to match with other monitors daemon started running as well. The active status also maintained after reboot.